# How to assign a dictionary with empty or null value

Tags: python

I have a code which uses a dict to create a bunch of key-value pairs.

The no. of key-value pairs is undefined and not fixed. In one iteration, it can have 2 key value, in another it can 4 or 5.

The way I am doing is I currently use an empty dict

like

```
cost_dict = {}
```

Now when a regular expression pattern is found in a text string then I extract part of those text as key value pairs and populate the above dict with it.

However wherever the pattern is not found, I am trying to catch that exception of AttributeError and then in that specific case I want this above dict to be assigned like null or blank value.

So like

```
cost_dict ={}
try:
   cost_breakdown = re.search(regex, output).group()
except AttributeError: 
   cost_dict =' ' # this part I am not sure how to do
... (if pattern matches extract the text and populate the above dict as key-value)
```

But I am not sure how to assign null or blank value to this dict then as above obviously creates a string variable cost_dict and does not assign it to the above defined empty dict.

Comment: What do you want `cost_dict` to look like after this assignment?

Comment: does collections.setdefault() not work in this case?

Comment: Make your regex group(s) not required with `?`

Comment: Do you have sample input and expected output? What are the key value pairs made of?

Comment: there is no set key value pair. That is why its difficult to give sample output. Think of a text string has a bunch of words and few numbers. Those bunch of words differ as each text line it comes across. 

I am taking the words as key and the numbers as value wherever the text line has a pattern. Here output is that text line. When the pattern is not found, then I want the dict to be empty otherwise , it will parse the text line (output above) and put the words as keys and numbers as values.

Comment: You can't provide even a *single* example?